# dbext Connection to SQL Server on OSX (/usr/local/bin/osql: illegal option -- w)

Tags: dbext

I've been trying to get dbext to connect to an external SQL server instance on OSX using MacVim.
So far I've tried a few iterations of different connection strings all of which return /usr/local/bin/osql: illegal option -- w.

This makes me think this may not be a connection string issue, but something involving osql or something else in the connection stack. However, I'm able to connect to the server in both tsql & isql in the terminal (which use osql), along with being able to get results from PERL scripts using DBI. /usr/local/bin/osql is the correct path for osql on my machine.

Example of full error:

```
Connection: T(SQLSRV)  H(<hostname>)  D(<db name>)  U(<user name>)   at 13:18
/usr/local/bin/osql: illegal option -- w
Syntax: osql -S server -U user -P password
To change connection parameters:
:DBPromptForBufferParameters
Or
:DBSetOption user|passwd|dsnname|srvname|dbname|host|port|...=<value>
:DBSetOption user=tiger:passwd=scott
Last command(rc=1):
osql -w 10000 -r -b -n -U <username>  -P<password>  -H <hostname>  -d <dbname>  -i <temp file path>/dbext.sql
Last SQL:
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM <table_name>
go
```

connection string formats I've tried (.vimrc):

```
let g:dbext_default_profile_Test0=DBI:user=<username>:passwd=<password>:dsnname=<TDS named DSN>'

let g:dbext_default_profile_Test1='type=SQLSRV:user=<username>:passwd=<password>:host=<host address>'

let g:dbext_default_profile_Test2='type=SQLSRV:user=<username>:passwd=<password>:dsnname=<TDS named DSN>:srvname=<boxname>'
```

I've tried re-installing FreeTDS, UnixODBC, & DBI. These seem to be working fine (still) when used independently of dbext.

What am I missing?
A correct answer is anything resulting in a connection: Either a change in one of the aux. products (FreeTDS, UnixODBC, Etc.) or a way I can work around the illegal option error in dbext through dbext (a connection string that plays nice with my current setup).

I've been banging my head against the wall for hours, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the DBI ODBC functionality. The documentation also seems to prefer this method for performance reasons.

For anyone else having the same problem make sure that the error strings being returned are the most recent version of TDS & Perl on your machine. In my case, it was looking in an old Perl directory that did not have the necessary DBI/DBD/ODBC drivers.

After I got the DBI side working by deleting the old directories I was able to connect with the below connection string.

```
let g:dbext_default_profile_<Profile_Name> = 'type=ODBC:user=<username>:passwd=<passwrd>:dsnname=<freeTDS DSN name>:driver=FreeTDS'
```

Hope this helps save some of the time I had to spend figuring out the config.